# Is it possible to make it work without using an interface?

Tags: go, types, interface

Why does the following work when I add type `Pet []interface{Name()}` but not when I add type `Pet []string`? Is it possible to make it work **without** using an interface?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Pet []string // cannot use Cat("Puss") (type Cat) as type string in array or slice literal
// type Pet []interface{Name()} // prt Fluffy

type Cat string

func (c Cat) Name() {
    fmt.Println(c)
}

func main() {
    p := Pet{Cat("Whiskers"), Cat("Fluffy")} 
    p1 := p[1]
    p1.Name() 
}

./oo3.go:15:14: cannot use Cat("Whiskers") (type Cat) as type string in array or slice literal
./oo3.go:15:31: cannot use Cat("Fluffy") (type Cat) as type string in array or slice literal
./oo3.go:17:4: p1.Name undefined (type string has no field or method Name)
```

Comment: Go's type system has no covariance. Stop doing inhertance based design, it does not work.

Comment: Good point. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `Pet`, when declared as a `[]string`, cannot be initialized with a value of type `Cat`, because `Cat` and `string` are different types. That's how the Go type system works. When you define a new type as `type name otherType`, `name` becomes a completely new type with the same memory layout as the underlying type. For instance, the new type would not have any of the methods defined for `otherType`. You can, however, convert a `Cat` to string:

```
    p := Pet{string(Cat("Whiskers")), string(Cat("Fluffy"))}
```

Then `Pet` is still an array of strings.

When you define `Pet` as an array of interfaces with `Name` method, then `Cat` now can be used to initialize elements of `Pet`, because `Cat` implements the `Name` method.

So in short: `Pet` as a `[]string` only holds string values. `Pet` as a `[]interface{Name{}}` holds any value that implements the `Name` method. If you need to call `Name` method on `Pet` elements, then you have to do it with an interface.

Comment: This is a great answer.  You've made it much clearer for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TomL Even though this answer explains quite well what is going on, your issue still remains. You tried making an inheritance structure which Go simple cannot do. You should look into composition instead.

Comment: @Bazzz. Thank you for your very good points. If I understand correctly trying to make an inheritance structure or a **is- a** relationship (as in Fluffy is a Cat) simply won't work in Go. I agree with you that I should look at composition or **has-a** (as in Cat has a Name) and **part-of-a** (as in Cat is part of a - as a new example - House) relationships as these are supported by Go.

Comment: @TomL correct! I would say the *is-a* relationship that you have tried is `Cat is a Pet`, not `Fluffy is a Cat`, but the rest remains as you say it. If you really want many classes to have a common set of behaviour you can define `Pet` as an interface and have it describe the common aspects in terms of operations. For example: All `Pet`s can `eat()`. If a `Cat` can `eat()`, it must be a `Pet`.

Comment: @Bazzz. Thank you again for your help.